# interface - Overridden methods are not inherited

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

I was reading Java SCJP book by Khalid A. Mughal (for JE6), and in topic 7.6 Interfaces and Page number 313, it is given that

> A subinterface can override abstract method declarations from its superinterfaces. Overridden methods are not inherited.

I could not quite understand what **"Overridden methods are not inherited."** means. I tried to do this:

```
interface A
{
    void abc();
}

interface B extends A
{
    @Override
    void abc();
}

interface C extends B
{
    void abc();
}
```

And I did not get any error. What am I not understanding?

Comment: Overriding methods does not apply to interfaces, only classes.

Comment: But in book it is said in context of `interfaces`

Comment: In Java 8, interfaces can have default implementations to methods but in earlier versions the concept of overriding doesn't make sense wrt interfaces.

Comment: but the book is for java version 6

Comment: @MickMnemonic You can override an abstract method declaration by another abstract method declaration. This can involve making the return type more restrictive or changing the list of exceptions thrown.

Comment: But if you change the method signature, you're defining a new method, not overriding the one from the superclass/interface.

Comment: Return types are not part of method signature

Comment: @ShubhamBatra Thanks for the quick checkmark, but I've added a big second section that I want to make sure you see as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simply means that overridden methods can have a slightly different signature than the superinterface's methods. For example:

```
public interface Foo {
    Object doSomething(String input) throws IOException;
}

public interface Bar extends Foo {
    @Override
    String doSomething(String input);
}
```

As you can see, in the subinterface, I no longer throw a checked exception, and I guarantee that the returned object is a more specific type. The method that *did* throw a checked exception is not inherited, because it is overridden.

---

I don't have the context of the entire paragraph, but there's something else related that applies only to implementations and not interfaces, which is that if you **override a method without explicitly calling `super`,** the superclass's implementation won't occur.

For example, if I have:

```
public class Example {
  public static class Foo {
    public void printSomething() {
      System.out.println("Foo");
    }
  }

  public static class Bar extends Foo {
    @Override
    public void printSomething() {
      System.out.println("Bar");
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Bar bar = new Bar();
    bar.printSomething();
  }
}
```

This program will simply output:

```
Bar
```

but NOT `Foo`. If I add a call to `super.printSomething()`, then it will print both.